# Which one gets more performance for dependency injection in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working together with .net core and dependency injection. But There is something I'm not sure about the performance. Usually, the services are defined in the constructor but I don't need some services inside the method. Doesn't it cause performance loss?

Is this a disadvantageous use in the following line?

```
    public ValuesController(ICompanyService companyService, IOnlineUserService onlineUserService, IXService xService, ..., ..., ..., ...,)
    {

    }
```

Isn't it more advantageus use this in the following line?

```
public virtual IActionResult UseCompanyServiceMethod()
        {
            ICompanyService _companyService = CtorContainer.Provider.GetRequiredService<ICompanyService>();
            /*
               ...
             */
        }

        public virtual IActionResult AnyMethod()
        {
            IOnlineUserService onlineUserService = CtorContainer.Provider.GetRequiredService<IOnlineUserService>();
            IXService xService = CtorContainer.Provider.GetRequiredService<IXService>();
            ... = CtorContainer.Provider.GetRequiredService <...> ();
            /*
               ...
             */
        }

        public virtual IActionResult Method()
        {
            ... = CtorContainer.Provider.GetRequiredService <...> ();
            ... = CtorContainer.Provider.GetRequiredService <...> ();
            ... = CtorContainer.Provider.GetRequiredService <...> ();
            ... = CtorContainer.Provider.GetRequiredService <...> ();
            /*
               ...
             */
        }
```

CtorContainer.cs

```
public static class CtorContainer
{
    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
    public static IMapper Mapper { get; set; }

    public static IServiceProvider Provider { get; set; }
}
```

startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        CtorContainer.Provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
```

Comment: Did you measure it to find out if its even an issue in your use case? Creatng instances should be rather fast, unless you do some CPU intensive or long running operations in the constructor, which of course you **shouldn't**

Comment: You can also inject services into controller actions if you dont wish to inject it via constructor. Just to `public IActionResult MyAction([FromServices]IMyService service) { .... }`

Comment: @Tseng I don't any test yet. I will measure when I have time. I agree, I think should be inside the method using CtorContainer.Provider

Comment: @gerryc.inc thank you but I'm using in another layer, I am not using on controller constructor. so, don't have Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll

Comment: Also, you can use AutoFac and use it's method injection: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html

Comment: @kursatsonmez: Using the container within your services isn't Dependency Injection anymore, its called Service Locator and is an anti-pattern. Service locator should be very limited to the usage/instantiation of dynamic command handlers and factories. Also due to the way ASP.NET Core handles scoped containers, this won't work and you will have severe memory leaks or exception messages (when trying to resolve scoped services from ASP.NET Core's application-wide container)

Comment: Don't try to do preemptive optimization if you have no issues. Use the regular constructor based one. Better fix your services constructor to remove the heavy code from constructors. Constructors are meant to be **FAST**, doing anything lengthly here (IO or CPU heavy work) is a no-go

Comment: @kursatsonmez Calling the BuildServiceProvider method causes Singleton to behave like Transient classes, and you make the code dependent. use this DI way doesn't mean anything

Comment: @tdayi: it's worse then that, it creates **two** containers. Resolving one instance from the static container will be a different instance than one resolved in services and controllers, since ASP.NET Core creates the provider before calling `Configure` method and its an application wide container, means whatever you resolve from there it will live as long as the application or disposed manually (which would only work for transient registered services). Its a can of worms

Comment: @Tseng Is there a solution to write an abstract class for custom dependency resolver with .net core?

Comment: Hm, thank you for all reply. Your comments it's really understandable and logical, right, will two containers exist more harmful. It seems the constructor is the best solution.